# Laravel Group Count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I want to ask how to implement Laravel Query with Multiple Group Count Result.

Basically it display the result of each voters in a barangay or town. However, aside from it I want to display the counts of voters if they are supporter or not labaled as 0 or 1 in their status.

```
public function brgy()
{
    $brgy = Voter::groupBy('brgy')           
            ->selectRaw('count(*) as total, brgy')
            ->get();
    return view('brgy', compact('brgy'));
}
```

Please help.